# install openfire on fedora10

Tags: installation, fedora, openfire

I've installed openfire before on fedora9 with no problem,

but now on a fedora10 machine,after I installed it,try to run "service openfire start",

it simply can't run,

I checked the log and it said:
nohup: cannot run command `/opt/openfire/jre/bin/java': No such file or directory

Has anyone met the same problem?

Plz help,thnx

Comment: do you have this working now? there are ways to ensure your java environment variables remain persistent

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your Java VM isn't installed.  OpenFire is Java-based, so no Java, no OpenFire.

If it is installed, then link your java executable via softlink to that location, i.e.:

```
ln -s /path/to/binary/of/java /opt/openfire/jre/bin/java
```

Comment: You're probably better off sym-linking the entire JRE to /opt/openfire/jre/ instead

Comment: @ophidian: I'd give you a +10 for that.